# NSLocalizedString fails on certain key-lookups. Corrupt .Strings file?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I´m currently working on localizing an iPhone application.

I have one build target pr. country, and several .Strings files pr. country. 
Each country has a minimum of 3 languages tied to it.

My problem is that certain lookups fail without reason in some languages.
Which lookups fail seem to be random too. Although it´s the same strings that fail every time.

I suspect some kind of .Strings file corruption.

Is there any tool for checking integrity of these files, or some common causes of corruption that I could look for.

Additional info:

- Files are UTF-8 format
- Lookup for 99% of keys work.
- Changing key-name for the lookup does not work.
- I have double checked that I´m looking up the key in the right bundle.

Any help is greatly appreciated as deadline looms in less than a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have invalid UTF-8 in the file. Open it in BBEdit and see if it gives you any warnings.

Comment: BBEdit helped me with its syntax highlighting to find the errors in my file! One of the lines said ** My comment instead of //** My comment.

This error masked the invalid text-lines and made xcode compile even though there were other errors in the document.